# Размер блока в Multicolumn

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/94a4j/
UL всегда растягивается до 100%. Как установить ширину на auto?

И вот что будет если у родительского блока установить float: left - http://jsfiddle.net/94a4j/1/

Answer (score 1):

Единственный способ залить элемент целиком, это сделать элемент типа inline-block и явно указать количество колонок.  Больше никаких манипуляций проводить не надо.

```
ul {
    -webkit-columns: 160px 2;
    -moz-columns: 160px 2;
    columns: 160px 2;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/94a4j/2/)**

Comment: Список должен быть "резиновым", поэтому column-count всегда должен быть auto

Answer (score 0):

auto Ширина колонок вычисляется автоматически на основе других свойств (column-count, column-gap).

[column-width](http://htmlbook.ru/css/column-width)

> Задаёт оптимальную ширину колонки в многоколоночном тексте. Реальная ширина колонки может быть больше введённого значения, сокращение указанной ширины приводит к отмене нескольких колонок, текст при этом выстраивается в одну колонку.

Comment: Прочтите еще раз вопрос и осмотрите код. Мне нужна не ширина колонок, а ширина самого блока UL